# No current user - getServerSideProps Next JS and AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make an user-authenticated GraphQL request on the serverside in `getServerSideProps` using AWS Amplify and Next JS.

Users in my AWS Database can only access the data if they are the **owner** of the document.

The error I get from this is **"No current user"**... (which is being logged on the server).
The problem is, that I need the user available in the getServerSideProps, so I can make the authenticated request happen.

Here is the code I currently have

**index.tsx:**

```
import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation, withSSRContext } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "../aws-exports";
Amplify.configure({ ...config, ssr: true });

function Index({ bankAccounts }: { bankAccounts: BankAccount[] }) {

  return (
    ...stuff...
  );
}
```

**index.tsx (getServerSideProps):**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { API } = withSSRContext(context);

  const result = (await API.graphql({
    query: listBankAccounts,
  })) as {
    data: ListBankAccountsQuery;
    errors: any[];
  };

  if (!result.errors) {
    return {
      props: {
        bankAccounts: result.data.listBankAccounts.items,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      bankAccounts: [],
    },
  };
};
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice you could offer!

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well. Were you able to solve the issue? The solution providing `authMode` didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you maybe just need to pass in `authMode` as well in your `API.graphql` call.

In the [SSR Support for AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/ssr-support-for-aws-amplify-javascript-libraries/) blog post, inside the section titled **Making an authenticated API request in getServerSideProps** you'll see a code sample that looks like the following (note the addition of `authMode` below, which I don't see in your code sample above):

````
  const { API } = withSSRContext(context)
  let movieData
  try {
    movieData = await API.graphql({
      query: listMovies,
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
    });
    console.log('movieData: ', movieData)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error fetching movies: ", err)
  }
  return {
    props: {
      movies: movieData ? movieData.data.listMovies.items : null
    }
  }
}```
````